# how to display command output on terminal using timeout

Tags: timeout

if i do `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null` it show the results on terminal. but i want to run this command for a specific period of time and show the results. for example, i tried

`timeout 10s dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nul` but i get no stdout / stderr on terminal.

i tried using some timeout options like "--preserve-status", "--foreground" and "-v --verbose" but i still get no output on the terminal.

is there a way i can get the results to show on terminal or even to a file?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `--foreground` option for `timeout` in combination with `INT` signal to  `dd`.

```
timeout --foreground -s INT 0.1 dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null
```

Documentation for `timeout` say:

```
--foreground
  when not running timeout directly from a shell prompt,
  allow COMMAND to read from the TTY and get TTY signals;
  in this mode, children of COMMAND will not be timed out
```

From what I can see trough traces etc. it looks like this works better for `dd`. Without `--foreground` the process get the `INT` signal [but then a `CONT`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/4edad9e1210dfaa4c8630bad16d0b2e6090de790/src/timeout.c#L236) to both `dd` and `timeout` which rapidly result in the process exiting. In very rare cases `dd` does get the time to process the `INT` signal, but that is not the norm.

With `--foreground` the `CONT` is never sent and `dd` get time to print the stats before exiting.

The `cleanup` function linked above is called on first iteration call to [`sigsuspend`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/4edad9e1210dfaa4c8630bad16d0b2e6090de790/src/timeout.c#L571).

`dd`s [`process_signals()`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/4edad9e1210dfaa4c8630bad16d0b2e6090de790/src/dd.c#L995) is extremely rarely called *after* `interrupt_signal` has been set when `CONT` is in process for `timeout` (i.e. `--foreground` not set).

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked!, i had forgotten to use the foreground in conjunction with the signal. and thanks for the extra explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display `dd`'s output on stderr (like interrupting a `dd` process with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>), use the SIGINT signal instead of the default SIGTERM:

```
timeout -s INT 10s dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null
```

To redirect stderr to file `logfile`, use

```
timeout -s INT 10s dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null 2> logfile
```

Comment: that actually makes sense, on theory it should work, but i tried with INT and TSTP signals still no output is emitted, even redirecting the stderr and stdout to the logfile, no output or error is shown at all.

Comment: one thing that i noticed is, redirecting the stderr (2>) to a file it works if I specify the verbose flag and do a Ctrl+C before the timeout interval time runs out. but if I let the timeout interval time finish on its own, nothing is written to the file, not even if I specify the INT signal flag to timeout

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
timeout -s INT --foreground 10s dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null
```